# Getting the filename from filefield Extjs widget

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Is there some way of getting the file name from the **filefield** widget in Extjs?

I could use the value below but this gives me a **c:\fakepath\blah** string. And in Internet Explorer its different again.

```
    xtype: 'filefield',
    itemId: 'fileupload-field',

    listeners: {
        change: function (fld, value) {
            var fuf = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#fileupload-field");
            //??
        }
    }
```

Rather than perform all this string manipulation *(which is harder than it seems since the path is not character escaped)* to get to the filename, I would expect that the filefield component would have a method or attribute which just gives me the filename

However looking at the [API](http://www.objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.form.field.File.html) I do not see anything that can help me.

Answer (score 4):

```
xtype: 'filefield',
itemId: 'fileupload-field',

listeners: {
    change: function (fld, value) {
        var newValue = value.replace(/^.*\\/, "");;
        fld.setRawValue(newValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of what this code does and how it answers the question.

Comment: / / denotes the start and end of regular expression. ^ - denotes start of string. . - denotes any character. * - denotes any character succeeding it can appear multiple times. So if you combine it all and read - replace "from the beginning any character including mutiple \ characters" with blank space. So that will leave a string like D:\Folder\filename.png with only filename.png

Answer (score 1):

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            title: 'Upload a Photo',
            width: 400,
            bodyPadding: 10,
            frame: true,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'filefield',
                name: 'photo',
                fieldLabel: 'Photo',
                labelWidth: 50,
                msgTarget: 'side',
                allowBlank: false,
                anchor: '100%',
                buttonText: 'Select Photo...',
                listeners: {
                    change: function(fld, value) {
                        alert(value.replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/g, ''));    

                    }
                }
            }]
        });
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/dgr

[Filefield with extjs 4.2 without fakepath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22302841/filefield-with-extjs-4-2-without-fakepath)

Comment: What is really weird is that *fakepath* works for chrome and IE in your sencha fiddle. But when I use it in my application I get fakepath for Chrome, but IE STILL always uses the ACTUAL path... this is driving me cRaZy...

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen your comment first in that topic I pasted my link above. What exact version of ExtJs do you use in your application? Try playing with versions in Sencha's fiddle, maybe it has something to do with a bug in some specific version of ExtJs

Comment: I tried. Its exactly the same version. In the sencha fiddle it works flawlessly but in my applicaiton it shows the real path in IE. I HATE Internet Explorer SO MUCH